# Request adding Raspberry Pi stack to off topic site list

Tags: feature-request, off-topic, flagging

I'm going through the new posts which is not something I usually have a lot of time to do and I'm seeing multiple questions for networking on Raspberry Pi device. There is now a stack specifically for Raspberries. It would be nice to redirect all of those questions about devices which are not in a normal production environment to that stack.

Comment: First you need to check that RPi networking questions would be topical on the RPi site. They used not to like too much of the technical, preferring for example to send OS questions to the U&L site. Further, there are very few people who care enough anymore to migrate away, just 12 occurred in the last 90 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the volume of RPi question is low please flag for a migration if you think it's worth a migration.

Our other close destinations are more used and in my own opinion are more related to ServerFault itself. By having destination that are related to us we target more user that posted there but for some reason(s) are on a gray line with our on-topic subject.

I agree with user9517's comment and I would add that usually RPi topic are all off-topic there. Don't get me wrong, I like RPi for small IoT project at home, but in a enterprise that need 24/7 hardware, a RPi is simply a bad practice.